# Zend framework 2 how to add class to select input

Tags: forms, zend-framework2

How can I add a class to a select drop down list.

Below is my attempt to do it. I have tried to do it with the attributes but this doesn't appear to work with select tag.

```
 $this->add(
            array(
                'type' => 'DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectSelect',
                'name' => 'jobId',
                'options' => array(
                    'object_manager' => $this->getObjectManager(),
                    'target_class'   => 'FormDependencies\Entity\JobList',
                    'property'       => 'job',
                    'empty_option'   => '--- please choose ---',
                     'attributes' => array(
                      'class'  => 'testing',
                       )
                ),
              )
           );
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

below is the rendered input bar: you will see that the class has not been added;

```
<select name="Jobs[jobId]">
```

Comment: Adding the `class` key is the way to go; Therefore, what you have tried should work (although the additional `)` bellow `class` key needs to be removed). Please elaborate on why it "doesn't appear to work"

Comment: Hi AlexP. sorry. i put the wrong one. the correct select box form is now in place

Comment: i am not clear why its not working. i have put up the select input bar. you will see that the class has not been added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `attributes` array should not be nested within `options`; but rather on the same level.

```
$this->add(array(
    'name' => 'jobId',
    'type' => 'DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectSelect',
    'options' => array(
        'foo' => 'bar'
    ),
    'attributes' => array(
        'class'  => 'testing',
    ),
));
```